# Running JavaScript on a Page via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

So I am writing a chrome extension that will (hopefully) improve Cookie Clicker.  As of right now, I have set up my `manifest.json` file to open up an HTML file when my extension's button is clicked. Here is the `.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function runScript()
{
var clickTiming = prompt("How many times per second would you like the cookie to be  clicked?");
var clickTimingInt = Math.floor(clickTiming);
var doClick = 1/clickTimingInt;
var autoClicker = setInterval(Game.ClickCookie, doClick);
(function () {
    var jA = document.createElement('script');
    jA.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    jA.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js');
    jA.onload = function() {
        var jB = document.createElement('script');
        jB.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        jB.setAttribute('src', 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2KRNm8Gm&' + new Date().getTime());
        document.body.appendChild(jB);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(jA);
}())
var interval = 500;
 
var cookieBot = setInterval(function() {
  Game.ObjectsById[optimalBuilding()].buy();
}, interval);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="runScript()">Run Script</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon the user pressing the "Run Script" button, I wanted my program to run the JavaScript on the page. However, when I press the button, nothing happens. I know that the HTML is fine, because when I open the file in Chrome, it works just dandy. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work via the extension. Is there a problem with my set-up, or is Chrome just unable to execute JavaScript on a page from an extension popup? If there is another way to do it that anyone knows of, please let me know!

Many thanks.

Comment: tampermonkey is far easier to use for cheating at online games...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using that html as your extension code forces the browser to execute that as a page that is popping up when you click the extension button. If you want to inject some JavaScript code inside the current page while pressing the extension button, you need to use chrome.tabs API (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html), particularly chrome.tabs.executeScript().

Read more about programmatic injections here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi.

First, you need to get the current tab, then inject your script. Your code should look like this:

```
<script>
    var tab;

    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        lastFocusedWindow: true
    },
    function(array_of_Tabs) {
        tab = array_of_Tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "// here should be your JavaScript code"});
    });
</script>
```

For more information read chrome.tabs API documentation provided above.